# One-to-many query

Tags: sql, one-to-many, sql-server-express

I have an hypothetical database as the image below were each plant can have a maximum of 4 colours.

[image: Database layout]

I wish to be able to return my results in a format similar to the below.

[image: Results]

If I run a standard query with Inner Join the results are duplicated were the plant has more than one colour. I have therefore tried running multiple separate queries were I first return the plant then a new query to return the colours. I then loop though colour result to produce the output I desire.

I assume there is a far for efficient way to achieve this?

I am trying to do this as a query and as a stored procedure so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Excellent. This is so much quicker and neater than my workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know there are a maximum of 4 colors, then you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select plantname,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then colorname end) as color_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then colorname end) as color_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then colorname end) as color_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then colorname end) as color_4
from (select p.plantname, p.plantid, c.colorname,
             row_number() over (partition by p.plantid order by c.colorid) as seqnum
      from plants p join
           plantcolors pc
           on pc.plantid = p.plantid join
           colors c
           on pc.colorid = c.colorid
     ) pc
group by plantname, plantid;
```

Comment: If I wanted to return more than the plant name from the plant table how could this be added to the above to achieve this? Some of the items will be from lookup tables.

Comment: @StephenH . . . One method is just to list the columns both in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I had done everything correct with the exception of including the column reference in the group by. That works great, just needed to include a join for those values contained in a lookup table.

Comment: I have just noted that if there is no colour for the plant entered it does not return the plant with 4 Null for the colours. is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @StephenH .  . Use `left join`s instead of inner joins.

Comment: Thank you for your response and patience with my questions.