# One-to-many query with conditional aggregation and how to retrieve distinct results from query

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I was kindly provided with a solution by a member [see original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147268/one-to-many-query-and-row-number-and-conditional-aggregation) that resulted in the following:

```
SELECT s.StampId 
   , ct.Country
   ,StatusTable.Status
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveUsed
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantUsed
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeUsed
FROM StampTable s
LEFT JOIN StampQuantatiesTable sq ON s.StampId = sq.StampId
LEFT JOIN QuantatiesTable q ON q.QuantatiesId = sq.QuantatiesId
left Join CountryTable ct on S.Country = ct.CountryId
Left Join StatusTable on q.StatusId= StatusTable.StatusId
GROUP BY s.StampId 
       , ct.Country
       ,StatusTable.Status
```

In my database it’s possible for a stamp to be in none or any combination of the 3 statusid groups. For me these groups represent ‘Have’, ‘Want’ & ‘Trade’.

If I include a WHERE statement on just one of the groups say ‘Have’ I get the correct result but if I do the same for two or more groups I get duplicate results.

My Question is how can I limit the returned results so that it does not include duplicates.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did conditional aggregation on `q.statusid` which in turn is joined with the `StatusTable.StatusId` so your `StatusTable.Status` can be difderent for the same `s.stampid, ct.Country`

You should not use the `StatusTable.Status` in the `group by` and also in `select` clause (though you can use aggregate function on `StatusTable.Status` in `select` clause)

Use following query:

```
SELECT s.StampId 
   , ct.Country
   -- ,StatusTable.Status -- or max, min, etc aggregate function on StatusTable.Status
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveUsed
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantUsed
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeUsed
FROM StampTable s
LEFT JOIN StampQuantatiesTable sq ON s.StampId = sq.StampId
LEFT JOIN QuantatiesTable q ON q.QuantatiesId = sq.QuantatiesId
left Join CountryTable ct on S.Country = ct.CountryId
Left Join StatusTable on q.StatusId= StatusTable.StatusId
GROUP BY s.StampId 
       , ct.Country
      -- ,StatusTable.Status
```